# Use of Brackets

Tags: php, syntax, brackets

I am reading a book about PHP and Object Oriented Design. I've found some code samples about the way the author uses the brackets that puzzles me a little. I let you a pair of samples below:

First sample:

```
print "Author: {$product->getProduct()};
```

Second sample:

```
$b = "{$this->title} ( {$this->producerMainName}, ";
$b .= "{$this->producerFirstName} )"; 
$b .=  ": page count - {$this->nPages}";
```

All I know about `print` construct, is that brackets around the arguments are not required (http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php).

Furthermore, with specific reference to the second example, I'm asking myself why has the author decided to use even round brackets: wouldn't it be redundant? Is it just intended to improve legibility, or is there any other reasons I cannot imagine?

Comment: the curly brackets are required as soon as the variable to be expanded inside of the double-quoted string is anything more complicated than **$variable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple actually. Inside a string context, like when wrapped in quotes, when you need to parse an object attribute like a method or property you wrap it inside curly braces.

So this can help explain the statement:
`print "Author: {$product->getProduct()};`

Now second example is just an extension of the first one, where the author has used multiple lines and round brackets for readability. It can be also written as:

```
$b  = "{$this->title}"; 
$b .= "({$this->producerMainName},{$this->producerFirstName})";
$b .= ": page count - {$this->nPages}";
```

Here supposing we had following values:

```
$this->title = "Author Details ";
$this->producerMainName = "Doe";
$this->producerFirstName = "John";
$this->nPages = 10;
```

Then if we had echoed `$b` after the assignments above we would get:

`Author Details (Doe,John): page count - 10`